# Why can’t I use a protocol required initializer when constraining protocol to a class?

Tags: swift

Swift won’t let me compile the following code with the error message

> Constructing an object of class type 'T' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer

on the indicated line. The used initializer is clearly required by the protocol. Moving the construction into the initializer causes the same issue. If I remove `where Self: ChannelUser` (and the code making use of its method) everything compiles. The issue can also be fixed by requiring the initializer in ChannelUser but that is obviously off the point.

Why is that the case? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
class ChannelUser {
    func ready() {
        print("ready")
    }
}

class A: ChannelUser {  // Cannot be used with MockChannelUser because the initializer takes an Int
    init(a: Int) {
        // do something clever with a
    }
}

class B: ChannelUser, MockableChannelUser {  // Can be used with MockChannelUser
    override required init() {}
}

protocol MockableChannelUser where Self: ChannelUser {
    init()
}

struct MockChannelUser<T: MockableChannelUser> {
    let user = T()  // Error: Constructing an object of class type 'T' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer

    init() {
        user.ready()
    }
}
```

Comment: "The issue can also be fixed by requiring the initializer in ChannelUser but that is obviously off the point." Isn't that the entire point? It's telling to mark `ChannelUser.init()` as `required`, which should be the solution. (And if `ChannelUser` already has an `init()`, what is the point of the init requirement? Is there more to your protocol? It's unclear what this protocol is trying to achieve.)

Comment: @RobNapier No. Not all ChannelUser subclasses must provide `init()`. But those that are intended to be used with MockChannelUser must provide it.

Comment: Interesting – looks like `T()` is resolving to `ChannelUser`'s `init()`, and the diagnostic isn't integrated into the constraint system so it doesn't consider `MockableChannelUser`'s `init()` requirement. This appears to be fixed on master though, [the diagnostic is now part of the constraint system](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/22379) so other solutions are also visited.